# How to compare Input JSON fields using the Jolt trasnformation

Tags: json, transform, jolt

I want to compare two input JSON fields using the Jolt transformation.
I have a input JSON and I want to compare the **FromStore** to **ToStore**  fields.
If **FromStore** and **ToStore** values are same then I want to remove the map in the List

```
[{
  "SlipNo": "3564300004",
  "FromStore": "1",
  "ToStore": "1",
  "CreatedDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
  "TotalQty": 3,
  "items": [
    {
      "UPC": "8240959370255",
      "shippedQuantity": 1
    },
    {
      "UPC": "8240959370266",
      "shippedQuantity": 1
    },
    {
      "UPC": "8240959370277",
      "shippedQuantity": 1
    }
  ]
},
{
  "SlipNo": "3564400006",
  "FromStore": "4",
  "ToStore": "3",
  "CreatedDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
  "TotalQty": 3,
  "items": [
    {
      "UPC": "8240959370210",
      "shippedQuantity": 1
    },
    {
      "UPC": "824095937011",
      "shippedQuantity": 1
    },
    {
      "UPC": "8240959370212",
      "shippedQuantity": 1
    }
  ]
}
]
```

**Expected output**

```
[
 {
    "SlipNo": "3564400006",
    "FromStore": "4",
    "ToStore": "3",
    "CreatedDate": "2022-05-18T08:20:23-04:00",
    "TotalQty": 3,
    "items": [
      {
        "UPC": "8240959370210",
        "shippedQuantity": 1
      },
      {
        "UPC": "824095937011",
        "shippedQuantity": 1
      },
      {
        "UPC": "8240959370212",
        "shippedQuantity": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Can anyone please help me out here!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use this spec to achieve result

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ToDivFrom": "=divide(@(1,ToStore),@(1,FromStore))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ToDivFrom": {
          "1.0": null,
          "*": {
            "@2": "[]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ToDivFrom": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: If FromStore and ToStore both are numeric values then there is a way to compare string values in the Jolt transform.